# Jenkins double quoted

Tags: curl, jenkins, sparql, rdf, jenkins-pipeline

Hello I'm creating a pipeline with Jenkins, I have this document:

```
def CompleteGraphUri = "http://172.16.0.81:58080/blazegraph/namespace/replicate- mishel/sparql?context-uri=http://lod.eurohelp.es/dataset/parkings"

def RDFParkings = "shacl/parkings.ttl"


node { stage('Upload RDF to blazegraph') {  
         sh 'curl -X POST -H Content-Type:text/turtle --data-binary @' + RDFParkings + '' + CompleteGraphUri    } }
```

I need the instruction looks like:

> curl -X POST -H Content-Type:text/turtle --data-binary @parkings.ttl
>   "http://172.16.0.81:58080/blazegraph/namespace/replicate-mishel/sparql?context-uri=http://lod.eurohelp.es/dataset/parkings"

but I'm getting something like:

> curl -X POST -H Content-Type:text/turtle --data-binary @parkings.ttl
>   'http://172.16.0.81:58080/blazegraph/namespace/replicate-mishel/sparql?context-uri=http://lod.eurohelp.es/dataset/parkings'

And I need double quotes instead single. Can you help me ?

Thank you for your attention.

Regards

Comment: Isn't it simply escaping the double quotes? I mean `\"`

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
sh 'curl -X POST -H Content-Type:text/turtle --data-binary @' + RDFParkings + '' + CompleteGraphUri
```

by

```
 sh 'curl -X POST -H Content-Type:text/turtle --data-binary @' + RDFParkings + ' "' + CompleteGraphUri + '"'
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to say that I try it and It doesn't works also. I try the solution that AKSW propose and neither.